# Javascript - cookie cleared after browser is closed?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to set cookie that would last after browser is closed. Though every-time I close browser, cookie disappears. I thought cookies supposed to be kept even if browser is closed? Unless specified to be deleted after some time?

For example:

```
console.log("cookies ", document.cookie)
document.cookie = "some_cookie=true; max-age=31536000";
```

First time opening page with this JS code, it prints `cookies`.

After refreshing browser, it prints `cookies some_cookie=true`

After closing browser and opening same page again, it prints `cookies`.

I tested on `Firefox 65.0.2 (64-bit), Chrome 72.0.3626.109 (Official Build) (64-bit) and Chromium 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit)` (for Chrome and Chromium had to use http server, because it would not allow to set cookies at all, if raw html file was opened directly).

Results are all the same, after I close browser, my cookie is deleted. I also checked if there was an option to clear cookies on closing browser, but it is not enabled.

Am I doing something wrong here? Or cookies are outdated and I should just stick to `localStorage`?

P.S. I tried using `max-age`, `expires` or not using those at all, but result is the same.

Comment: You tried `expires` but did you try it with a date in UTC format? `new Date(Date.now() + 31536000).toUTCString()`

Comment: In your browser’s developer tools, there should be a list of cookies. Firefox, the Storage tab; Chrome, the Application tab. When does that list say your cookie expires?

Comment: @remix23 well that does not change anything. Also is it really required to set expiration time? Cause I tried to not setting any expiration, but result is still the same.

Comment: @Ry It says `expires on: Session`. Do I need to explicitly specify cookie to expire differently? Cause it looks like it is set to expire on session closing. Or it is browser setting? If its browser setting than it is really confusing, because option to delete cookies on closing browser is not enabled..

Comment: @Andrius: In every browser, even when using the HTTP server? That’s strange. Do you have any extensions installed in all of those browsers?

Comment: @remix23 It actually worked with `max-age=31536000`. But it only works if http server is used. If plain html file is opened and closed, it clears cookies even if developer tools says it expires on some date. It seems default expiration mode is on session and you need to specify duration how long cookie can persist. Don't know if there is a way to make cookie stay permanently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me what worked, was to specify `max-age` when storing cookie. But also when testing I had to use web server to serve my html file, because opening plain html file directly on browser, does not make it to be stored up to specified duration. Even if it says it will expire on some date, it still deletes cookie when browser is closed (this is kind of inconsistent).

So default behavior is it expires when session is closed, and to change that, need to specify some duration via `expires` or `max-age` attributes.

As per Mozzila documentation: "If neither expires nor max-age specified it will expire at the end of session."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#Write_a_new_cookie